# Beginner SQL question(s)

Tags: sql, database

I am two months in to an intro SQL course, it's late at night, and I am drawing a blank.

I have two tables, one customers, and one orders.  I have to increase any customers credit limit by twenty five percent for all customers who have made two or more orders in which each order is more than the amount of 250.00.

I get how to `UPDATE CreditLimit * 1.25 and Cust with an order > 250`, but how do I get it to check if they have made two orders over 250?

Second question, we are just starting to take subqueries, and I am having a difficult time getting it into my skull.  Another question posed by the prof of our class is to increase the credit limit of a customer who has an order that exceeds their credit limit. (Credit limit is on a customers table, order and amount are on an orders table). I then take that customer and UPDATE his CreditLimit +1000.

Comment: You've asked enough questions to know there isn't a limit -- keep questions separate, and specify a database because they all don't work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming by 'have made two orders' that it is implied that they've made at least 2 orders. If exactly 2, then ofc is = 2.

Edit : And as per Ravi's interpretation, "2 orders over 250" could also mean a cumulative spend by the customer. This is of course why ambiguous requirements sink projects.

```
UPDATE c
SET c.CreditLimit = c.CreditLimit * 1.25
FROM Customers c
WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders o WHERE o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId AND o.OrderAmount > 250)
>= 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I know this is just easy stuff for you guys, but holy smokes I find it tough to wrap around.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part: Use `GROUP BY` the customerID and `SUM` all the transactions. You can then get all the customer accounts who made transactions summing up more than 250.

```
SELECT CustomerID 
FROM t_customers c INNER JOIN t_orders o ON c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID 
GROUP BY CustomerID 
HAVING SUM(TransactionAmnt) > 250;
```

You can refer this article for more information on Subqueries: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Customers
SET CreditLimit = CreditLimit * 1.25
FROM (
  SELECT CustomerId
  FROM Orders
  WHERE OrderTotal > 250
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) o
WHERE o.CustomerId = Customers.Id
```